# Download Video File in java throwing socket write error only on safari browser

Tags: java, java-7, java-io

while trying to download a video file from repository is throwing socket write error only on safari browser. It is working fine with other browsers. Am not sure whether it is browser issue or code issue.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(aFile);//File is loading here properly.
try {                   
   byte[] buf = new byte[32768]; // 4K buffer
   int bytesRead;
   while ( ( bytesRead = is.read( buf, 0, 32768 ) ) > 0 ) {
      out.write(buf,0,bytesRead );
   }
}
finally {
   if ( is != null ) is.close();
   if ( stampedFile != null && enableProofText )
   {
      if ( !stampedFile.delete() )
      {
         throw new IOException();
      }
   }
}
```

Below is the error,

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
08:47:00,297 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-180-10)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:403)
08:47:00,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-180-10)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:354)
08:47:00,299 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-180-10)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:426)
08:47:00,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-180-10)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:415)
08:47:00,300 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-180-10)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
```

Am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get why `32768` is `4k` since `4*1024=4096`. And don't you want to extract as a constant?
Does it mean that this is working with Chrome, Firefox or Opera?

Comment: Can you add a `catch` clause and print out the exception?

Comment: I tried with 4096 as byte size, but its not working. That is why I increased the byte size.

Comment: From Tomcat doc: `java.io.IOException - An underlying IOException occurred`. It doesn't say more.

Comment: But it is working in chrome, firefox etc.

Comment: Are you sure that your socket is opened/closed properly? (With exception handling, ...)